# Endianness for all c data types on Windows OS

Tags: c, windows, endianness

I am trying to document the different data types and how they are stored in memory in C. I know how many bytes each data type takes up but I would like to know how the endianness of every data type. This is specifically for Windows.

Comment: Endianness is a function of the processor, not the operating system.  x86-type processors are little-endian.  Other processors are big-endian.  It's also unlikely to be a function of the data type.  A little-endian machine will normally be little-endian for all basic data types.  Similarly for a big-endian machine.

Comment: What you do is declare a variable, and assign a value to it. Then either look at the memory for that variable with a debugger, or print the bytes separately. For example if an `int` is 4 bytes, `int n = 0x12345678; unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&n; for (int i=0; i<4; i++) printf("%x ", *p++);` will print `78 56 34 12` on a little endian system, and `12 34 56 78` on a big endian system.

Comment: For floating point types, you'll need a basic understanding of the representation of floating point values. Then you'll need to choose a value, like `1.0` that makes it easy to tell which endianness is being used. See for example, see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Endianness)

Comment: If you have integer data stored in a binary file, its endianness will naturally be the same as the system which writes it (unless contrived to reverse it). When reading from a binary file, its endianness is not affected by the system that is reading it (unless it purposely reverses it). Standard file formats usually have their endianness defined in their spec, and it is up the the programmer to ensure it matches the endianness of the system reading it, or to flip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endianness is (usually) a function of the hardware, not the OS or the language, so all multi-byte types *should* have the same endianness.

Emphasis on *should*.

For x86 and x86_64 (on which Windows primarily runs), all multi-byte types are little-endian.

But there are always going to be some oddball platforms.  The DEC VAX was little-endian  except for floating-point types, which were stored in a *combined* big- and little-endian order.  From Kapps & Stafford<sup>1</sup>:

> The VAX was designed in part to be compatible with the PDP-11 computer.  The PDP-11 is a 16-bit machine, and 32-bit and 64-bit floating point numbers were stored as sequences of 16-bit words with the **most significant** part coming first.  This was unfortunate for the VAX, because the VAX almost universally places the **least significant** part first.  Floating-point numbers are the main exception to this rule.  As a consequence, when an F_floating number is stored in a longword, we have to reverse the first 16 bits with the last 16 bits.

IOW, each 16-bit word was big-endian (byte order `01`), but the sequence of 16-bit words was little-endian, so the byte order of a 32-bit `F_float` was `2301`.

As for type sizes...

C does not specify sizes for the "traditional" scalar types like `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, etc.  It specifies a *minimum range of values* that each type must be able to represent.  A `char` must be able to represent all characters in the basic execution character set, meaning it must be *at least* 8 bits wide, but it may be wider (9-bit bytes and 36-bit words are a thing, or at least used to be).  An `int` must be able to represent values in *at least* the range `-32767..32767`, meaning it must be *at least* 16 bits wide.

---

1. Kapps, Charles A. and Robert L. Stafford, *VAX Assembly Language and Architecture*, Prindle, Weber & Schmidt 1985

Comment: A quibble: The fact that `char` can represent all characters in the basic execution character set only implies that it's at least 7 bits. There are separate explicit requirements that `CHAR_BIT >= 8`, and that either `CHAR_MIN == 0 && CHAR_MAX >= 255` or `CHAR_MIN <= -127 && CHAR_MAX >= 127`.

Answer (score 0):

> I know how many bytes each data type takes up

That's impossible. C doesn't define sizes for any of its types. It only provides [minimums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types). For example, an `int` need only be 16 bits in size, but it's common for it to be larger. This can vary between compiler and OS.

> I would like to know how the endianness of every data type.

C doesn't define this either. It's going to depend on the hardware of the system. For example, x86 and x86_64 are little-endian. ARM is big-endian. And some old systems use byte orders that are different than both of these.